# Realm DB - How to decrypt the Realm DB in Android?

Tags: android, realm

I am working in application where I need to keep my DB secure, Hence I am using realm DB with `SecureRandom` class which is available in java.

Here is my problem - I have gone through the couple of samples by using that I am able to encrypt the DB. But when I re launch the application it's is crashing and below is code and logs

Excepted Result: I want to decrypt the DB and re launch the application.

Could some here please suggest how to decrypt the Realm DB.

```
Realm.init(this);

        byte[] key = new byte[64];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);

        Log.v("Test", Util.bytesToHex(key));

        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(mTableName)
                .encryptionKey(key)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Decrypt Method:

```
private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

Crash Logs:

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/com.trident.dpperformance/files/Trident_DB': Realm file decryption failed Path:. (Realm file decryption failed Path: /data/data/com.trident.dpperformance/files/Trident_DB) (/data/data/com.trident.dpperformance/files/Trident_DB) in /Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master2/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:171)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:241)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:231)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:318)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
        at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:407)
        at com.trident.dbperformance.RealmController.<init>(RealmController.java:17)
        at com.trident.dbperformance.RealmController.with(RealmController.java:22)
        at com.trident.dbperformance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate a key using `new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);` this approach. Every time you'll open the app this will generate a new random key. Whereas when it comes to Realm you have to use the same key every time to encrypt and decrypt.

More information on how to encrypt and properly store encryption-key as per Realm documents: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/advanced-guides/encryption/